# Is there a way to simplify this ternary statement?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So what I have at the moment is the following:

```
responseJson.put("barcode", 
    response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode)) == null 
        ? "" 
        : Base64.encodeToString(response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode)), 
            Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Basically what I want to do in a nutshell is evaluate if the database call returns null, if it does then populate the JSON with an empty string otherwise with the value in the database.

I feel that I am maybe missing something here and would like to not do two calls to the database, so I know that I can create a variable to only do the call once and store the value in there, but was wondering if there was a different way to do this?

Comment: How about getting the blob ahead of the ternary?

Comment: Java doesn’t have a null coalesce operator so it’s best to use a variable.

Comment: Didn't find any issue but, `response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode))` statement is executed twice, can be stored in a variable first before passing it to ternary.

Comment: There is no issue code. But response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode)) statement executed 2 times. May be response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode)) is returning not NULL

Answer (score 1):

Just make a single DB call and then reuse the results:

```
byte[] barcode = response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode));
responseJson.put("barcode", barcode == null ? "" : 
    Base64.encodeToString(barcode, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

But this would probably be easier to read and maintain if written as an `if` statement:

```
byte[] barcode = response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode));
String value = "";
if (barcode != null) {
    value = Base64.encodeToString(barcode, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
responseJson.put("barcode", value);
```

Comment: Yeah that was the plan, was just curious if there was another way to do this all together, trying to save lines of code here :P

Comment: There are many ways. Saving code lines is no noble goal. Readability is king.

Comment: @OleV.V. ... but don't tell that to a Scala person ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Tim Biegeleisen's answer is the most efficient, but as one expression:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(
       response.getBlob(response.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.rBarcode)))
   .map(Base64::encodeToString)
   .orElse(""));
```